# How to call a JavaScript function in page from another page

Tags: php, javascript

I have a mainpage page1.php, in page1.php I disabled some buttons and it also has div tag.
In that div I am calling search.php page.
The search form is submitting to another page page3.php and page 3 obviously load in div tag only. Such that I am maintaining page1 matter as common to all pages.
Whenever user submitted search form I want to enable some buttons in page1.php.
How it can be possible? Please suggest.

Comment: You can do it with cookies.

Comment: You are submitting to another page. Via AJAX or not?

Comment: no. just like form submitting in php.                            <form method="post" action="page3.php">

Comment: disable and enable is working fine in the page1.php itself with following function. function show()
{
 var list = document.querySelectorAll(".button2");
 var index;
 for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].disabled = false;}
}

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and `$.load()` Or `$.post()` function

in page2.php for example :

```
<script>$('#button1').removeAttr('disabled');</script>
```

that `#button1` exist in page1.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the script in the page. This is how:

1. Seperate the search page and its scripts in a file, e.g 'searchscripts.php'.
2. Reference the code in pages page1.php and search.php with:

   ```
   <?php
   include_once 'searchscript.php'
   ?>
   ```